# I am looking for a online text editor just like physics stack exchange

Tags: feature-request, resource-recommendation

I hope this question is suitable for discussing here.

I've been hanging around on PSE, I found the text editor of this site is very good and simple(Markdown+Mathjax). I hope to find an online editor just as PSE, with a preview pane, the syntax is same, support math equations.

I also want that I can save the manuscript on the server and get the sharing links so that I can send it to anyone.

In summary, what I wanted is writing a post on PSE however this post would not bother anyone unless I share the link with them. Because some question may be too specific and no need to be seen to all the people, or maybe sometimes I want to discuss a questions with my friends privately.

I wonder if PSE can offer this feature or anyone know a free online website fits all my requirements?

Comment: quicklatex is helpful for equations alone, although this is a partial answer to your query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/), or [PageDown](http://pagedown.googlecode.com/hg/demo/browser/demo.html). The latter is the open source engine that SE uses, the former is an editor based on SE's flavor of markdown.

Comment: It looks great, but I can't save online and get an share link on both website.

Comment: @luming Well, it should be pretty easy to set up a server with markdownsharp and pagedown to do this, but I don't think this exists currently.

Comment: @luming StackEdit has a fair bit of sharing capabilities, though you may need to depend on an external hosting like dropbox or google drive. Click on the `#` button on the top left.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Really nice feature, that's all I need.